# how to achieve horisontal card scroll effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have been trying to achieve a horisontal scrolling effect for a while but nothing seems to be working. Not too keen on using third party libaries either has I have had some issues with them. Here is what it looks like right now[image]
Any idea on how to make a scroll effect when I press the next or prev buttons?

I have tried this:

```
/* This is the style for the first card when the next button is clicked */
.voicecard-0.next {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

/* This is the style for the second card when the next button is clicked */
.voicecard-1.next {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

/* This is the style for the fifth card when the next button is clicked */
.voicecard-5.next {
  transform: translateX(50%);
}

/* This is the style for the sixth card when the next button is clicked */
.voicecard-6.next {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

/* This is the style for the first card when the prev button is clicked */
.voicecard-0.prev {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

/* This is the style for the second card when the prev button is clicked */
.voicecard-1.prev {
  transform: translateX(50%);
}

/* This is the style for the fifth card when the prev button is clicked */
.voicecard-5.prev {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

/* This is the style for the sixth card when the prev button is clicked */
.voicecard-6.prev {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

And the corresponding jsx

```
div id="card-container" className={`flex space-x-3 slide-${currentPage}`}>
  {data.slice(startIndex, endIndex).map((card, index) => (
    <div key={card.id} className="card-container" style={{ transform: `translateX(${index * 100}%)` }}>
      <VoiceCard img={card.img} name={card.name} />
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

But I can't get it to work, for context here is the component where this is located:

```
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
import { useState } from "react";
import { Input } from "./ui/input";
import Button from "./ui/button";
import VoiceCard from "./voicecard";
import data from "../lib/dummydata"
import { debounce } from "lodash";
import { ChevronRight, ChevronLeft } from "lucide-react";


const Home = () => {
  // making sure only 6 cards are displayed per "page"
  const cardsPerPage = 6;
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

  // calculates total pages by rounding up to nearest int
  const totalPages = Math.ceil(data.length / cardsPerPage);
  const startIndex = (currentPage -1) * cardsPerPage;
  const endIndex = startIndex + cardsPerPage;

  // event handlers for the next and prev buttons
  // debounce is used to prevent page flickering on rapid clicking
  const handleNextPage = debounce(() => {
    setCurrentPage((prevPage) => Math.min(prevPage + 1, totalPages));
  }, 600);

  const handlePrevPage = debounce(() => {
    setCurrentPage((prevPage) => Math.max(prevPage - 1, 1));
  }, 400);


  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center w-screen">
      <div id="home-container" className="grad-background flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
        <div id="top-text" className="flex flex-col items-center pb-4">
          <span>⭐ ⭐ ⭐ ⭐</span>
          <h2 className="font-semibold">stuff</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="main-text" className="text-center">
          <h1 className="font-semibold">stuff </h1>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom-text" className="pt-4">
          <h2 className="font-semibold" id="biline">stuff</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="search-bar" className="pt-3 w-full flex flex-col items-center">
          <div className="landing-search flex">
            <Input placeholder="Sök efter röster" />
            <Button id="search-button"></Button>
          </div>
          <div id="start-button" className="pt-7">
            <Button>Starta nu</Button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="button-container" className="flex space-x-1 items-center ml-auto pt-8">
          <div id="trending-text" className="">
            <h3 className="font-semibold pl-">stuff</h3>
          </div>
          <button onClick={handlePrevPage} disabled={currentPage === 1}  className="bg-white rounded-full w-30 h-15 border-2 border-gray-200 ">
            <ChevronLeft />
          </button>
          <button onClick={handleNextPage} disabled={currentPage === totalPages} className="bg-white rounded-full w-30 h-15 border-2 border-gray-200 ">
            <ChevronRight/>
          </button>
          <Button variant="outline">Visa alla</Button>
        </div>
        <div id="card-container" className="flex space-x-3" >
        {data.slice(startIndex, endIndex).map((card) => 
          <VoiceCard key={card.id} img={card.img} name={card.name} />
        )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


export default Home;
```

Also here is the component I am using for "voicecard" if it helps

```
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
import { Play } from "lucide-react";

const VoiceCard = ({ img, name}) => {
  return (
    <div id="voice-card" className="flex flex-col pt-2">
      <img className="w-40 h-25 rounded-full" src={img}></img>
        <div className="flex">
        <h3 className="font-semibold" id="card-name">{name}</h3>
        <Play />
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default VoiceCard;
```

I would be very grateful if someone would take time out of their day to help me!

Comment: What happens when prev/next are clicked? Side note, having CSS like that for each individual card seems strange.

Comment: @Kalnode The next cards are rendered instantly eg female 7, 8 and so on, looks weird, which is why I wanted the animation.

Comment: Well, I would think you would perform one single CSS transform on the entire carousel, not transforms on each individual item. There is also the option of doing this all with scrolling events (ie no CSS anims or transforms) which may be more performant (transforms invoke re-draw operations).

Comment: @Kalnode Makes sense thank you, will try.